# auto height & scroll in middle div - possible?

Tags: css

I want:

```
<div style="height:100%">
  <div style="height:70px;">header</div>
  <div style="overflow-y:scroll;">main</div>
  <div style="height:60px;">footer, alw. at bottom parent-div</div>
</div>
```

The real (px) container height may change dep on client window-size,
height of footer and header set in css-theme.

All positioning should be relative. Is JS required to solve this?

(Tried height:auto on main, seem to have no effect.)

Comment: `height: auto;` is the default behavior for a `div`. do you only want your main div to scroll when the window size is reached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `absolute` positioning to achieve this quite easily, why should it be positioned `relative`?.

```
#header, #main, #footer {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}     

#header {
    top: 0;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#main {
    top: 70px;
    bottom: 60px;
    background-color: lime;
    overflow: auto;  
}

#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tg8g5/**